# Sending data from one component to another

Tags: angular

Bonjour,

Here is the component tree of my application:

```
--data
  --graphic

--assetsStatus
  --location.compenent
  --vente.compenent
```

So I would like to send data from the assetsStatus components to the component data to feed a graph.

Thank you

Comment: Use `@Output()` event emitter

Comment: This has already been extensively covered. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bangular%5D+one+component+to+another) and [here](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services).

Comment: Faisal:  i can't use @Output ? This is not a parent composent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the components are unrelated , then you can use service. If your components have parent child relationship then you can use @Input @Output way.

For your scenario you can use one generic service.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable()
export class ShareService  {   
  constructor() { } 
  private paramSource = new BehaviorSubject("");// inside bracket you can send any type
  sharedData = this.paramSource.asObservable();
  setParam(param:string) { this.paramSource.next(param)}    
}
```

add to providers in appmodule `providers:[ShareService ]`

set in constructors.

```
constructor(private shareService: ShareService  ){}
```

to set in service

```
this.shareService.setParam('Sending param');
```

to get from service

```
 this.shareService.sharedData.subscribe(data=> { console.log(data); })
```

Comment: Thank you for that answer.
It works very well on (data=> { console.log(data); }) but when I do (data => this.data = data);
    console.log(this.data); it doesn't work.